What model Arrowhead hydrant stem is this?
I have an old hydrant outside of my house that leaks. I am trying to find its model to figure out which replacement stem it needs.
Visually (pictured below), it looks like Arrowhead 420 Anti-Siphon Series, which this repair guide says needs a PK200X stem.

The existing stem, pictured below, is 10 7/16" long.

The repair guide says that uneven length stems should be 1/4" longer, so I tried the closest by length - which is PK2006SP (pictured below). It looks different from the existing stem, did not quite fit, and did not block water.

Note the check assembly at the end, which can be separated from PK2006SP, but is absent from the original stem, which is one continuous piece.
The original stem looks similar to PK800X stems. Except the end with rubber (pictured below) is round vs square in PK800X.

Which hydrant / stem model is this?

Your best bet may be taking the old one to a plumbing supply store.
